# Como remover uma posição de um ArrayBuffer em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse **ArrayBuffer** abaixo e preciso remover desse array a posição que tem o valor 21

Já tentei usar o `splice(24,1)` e também o `delete array[24]` e nenhum funcionou?

Alguem sabe como consigo apenas remover essa posição do **ArrayBuffer**?

```
<Buffer 01 a6 31 35 cb 12 00 08 7d cb b8 ae c5 3e 2d 0e 1e d0 fe 29 4e 61 fd 01 21 a0 00 c0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 24 03 19 15 cb 0b 3b 26 06 0b 31 00 ...>
```

Comment: Como você fez com o splice(24,1) para ele não funcionar? Pode postar o código pra gente?

Comment: if (pacote[i].toString(16) == 10) {
      pacote[i] = parseInt(pacote[i + 1].toString(16)) - 20;
     pacote.splice(i + 1, 1);
    }

Comment: Retornando isso:

    pacote.splice(i + 1, 1);
             ^
TypeError: Object �15�
@PauloHDSousa

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar o operador '-='. Imaginemos que temos o seguinte:

```
val valor = ArrayBuffer('1', '2', '3', '4', '21')
```

Para eliminar o valor 21:

```
valor -= '21'
```

Se queremos eliminar mais do que um valor:

```
valor -= ('21', '4')
```

Comment: está retornando NaN o novo array, lembrando que é um ArrayBuffer de Bytes

Comment: e no caso de ter dois valores 21?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim, que ele irá remover o elemento do array:

```
 ArrayBuffer.forEach(function(value, index) {
       if (value == '21') {
            ArrayBuffer.splice(index, 1);
       }
 });
```

[**Veja funcionando aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/p1rstzyy/)